# Filtering the magento shipping method

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods

I want to change the shipping method to be set according to the user country.I mean if a user select country A then he should be having shipping method say fed-ex for country A.And if he chose country B then method should be upsc of country B.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure shipping method for specific country from magento admin.

Here is the way : `System -> Config -> Shipping Methods (under **sales** tab )`

- Select you shipping method ex. fed-ex
- There is two values to setup shipping method i.e. ( `Ship to Applicable Countries` and `Specific Countries`.
- Choose **Specific Countries** in `Ship to Applicable Countries`
- Choose countries from `Specific Countries`
- save

Comment: Don't just copy others answer

Comment: is this copied ?